# When I have a new iPhone, can I unlink the old one from my iCloud identity?

Tags: ios, icloud

I got the new iPhone 14 Pro and was wondering if I can unlink my old iPhone from my identity, while still keeping iCloud activated on the device.

- For example, a contact tried to send me some photos via AirDrop, but selecting my Contact picture wouldn't work, instead they had to choose the device separately.
- Another example is my alarm clock. Each day, the alarm goes off on both phones, so I need to turn the old one off each evening.

I would like to keep iCloud active on the old phone if possible, as I use it as a backup device, so connectivity with my Cloud service is much appreciated.

Does anyone of you know how I can achieve this ideally without turning off iCloud for both phones?

Comment: You can always safely delete a device from find my. It will show up again next time it’s online, so let’s solve the other main question first and you can come back to find my later ifneeded with a follow up question.

Comment: While true, you shouldn't delete devices you own unless you want to remove the ability to track the device.

Answer (score 1):

> I got the new iPhone 14 Pro and was wondering if I can unlink my old
> iPhone from my identity, while still keeping iCloud activated on the
> device.

In general, this isn't possible and shouldn't be necessary. You either stay signed in, or you sign out.

> For example, a contact tried to send me some photos via AirDrop, but
> selecting my Contact picture wouldn't work, instead they had to choose
> the device separately.

This could be due to something that hasn't propagated yet, usually selecting a Contact picture appears on all signed in devices and goes to the first one that accepts it.

> Another example would be my alarm clock. Each
> day, the alarm goes off on both phones, so I need to turn the old one off each evening.

You need to delete your alarm from the old phone.

> Also, can I safely delete it from my device list in
> "Find my"?

You should do this if you plan on selling the phone. There's no reason to do this if you're keeping the device.

To avoid Find My left behind notifications, open Find My and select the device. You can disable "Notify When Left Behind" on this screen.

Comment: So, do I need to wait longer and the Contact picture AirDrop thing will resolve itself? Or do I need to do something?

The thing with my alarm is that it is the one from my sleep focus, which automatically is copied from my new phone to my old one. Don't know if I can do anything against it.

I wanted to delete it from my devices, because it keeps telling me that I left it behind...

Comment: For the alarm, are you disabling the actual alarm or just silencing it for one night? Open Health > Sleep > Full Schedule and edit your schedule to have no alarm. Let me know if this syncs back to your new phone...

Comment: For the Contact picture thing, I would try again. Share it to your contact picture and wait a few minutes and see if it appears on both devices again. It may not have worked the first time.

Answer (score 0):

**1st** possible solution: On the new phone you can go to Settings, click on your photo (AppleID), and there you'll see a list with devices that are logged-on with your AppleID. Then you can **remove a device** from your account.
**2nd** possible solution: On a computer go to https://www.icloud.com/settings/ and Log-in with your credentials. Find "Devices" and click on any of the listed. There will appear a list, and you can delete any of them from it.
Then the old phone will be disconnected from your iCloud account but all files on it will remain on the device. Then you can make a new Apple ID, to use with your old phone, for example "iPhone11Pro.myAppleID@iCloud.com" and activate it on your old phone. If at some point you need to access your 1st iCloud on you old phone, you can log-in with your 1st AppleID.
I think that alarms are part of the "Reminders", which are kept on iCloud. Having two different AppleID's for the two phones is the way to make different settings on them.